# Unbounded self-adjoint "nth-root"operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Suppose we have a self-adjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$ such that there exist $n>1$ that $T^n=1$ on $\mathrm{Dom}(T^n)$. Does it mean that $T$ is bounded ? If not, what are the minimal assumptions that implies this ?

Comment: I suspect that we can only have this with $T \neq 1$ (on its domain) if $n$ is even, which would mean that we can exploit the positivity of $T^*T$.

Comment: I think that the main problem could arise when $\mathrm{Ran}(T)$ is essentially smaller than the $\mathrm{Dom}(T)$. For example for $n=2$ if it is not that case we have both $T^{-1}$ and $T^\ast$ defined on the dense domain and they are equal there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator $T$ would be closed and densely-defined to qualify as selfadjoint. If $T^n=I$ on $\mathcal{D}(T^n)$, then the following holds on $\mathcal{D}(T^n)$, which is a dense subspace for any selfadjoint $T$:
$$
          (1-\lambda^n)I=T^n - \lambda^n I = (T-\lambda I)(T^{n-1}+\lambda T^{n-2}+\cdots + \lambda^{n-1}I).
$$
Because $T$ is selfadjont, then $T-\lambda I$ is invertible for non-real $\lambda$, and the resolvent $R(\lambda)=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ must satisfy
$$
           (1-\lambda^n)R(\lambda)=T^{n-1}+\lambda T^{n-2}+\cdots +\lambda^{n-1}I, \;\; \mbox{on}\; \mathcal{D}(T^n).
$$
Differentiating $n-2$ times gives
$$
           \frac{d^{n-2}}{d\lambda^{n-2}}((1-\lambda^n)R(\lambda)x)=(n-2)!Tx+\lambda(n-1)!x,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(T^{n}).
$$
The left side is a bounded operator for any non-real $\lambda$ because the resolvent and all of its derivatives are bounded operators. So $T$ is bounded on $\mathcal{D}(T^n)$. Because $T$ is closed and densely-defined, then $T$ is bounded with domain $H$.